# NetInfo addeventListener has a weird behaviour on ios

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-community-netinfo

Importing NetInfo from 'react-native' works very well on iOS and android. Although, now trying to import it from @react-native-community/netinfo (version 3.2.1) working on android with no problems but on iOS launching in a repetitive way the `addEventListener`. But @react-native-community/netinfo (version 4.*.* works on iOS without repetitive loop).

Here is my simple code with a console :

```
    import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo'

      onChangeConnexion() {

         NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
         console.log("hello world!")
          if(isConnected) {
           this.setState({ netIsConnected: true, netMessage: "" }, () => {

                       }) 
               } else {
         this.setState({ netIsConnected: false, netMessage: 
        NO_CONNECTION_TRAD[_this.props.lang] })
          }
             });
       }
       componentWillUnmount() {
          NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('connectionChange', 
            this.onChangeConnexion)

                 }


          componentDidMount() {

         NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', 
           this.onChangeConnexion)   // ON CHANGE

        }
```

hello world ! is written in a loop way when launching app. That means that the `addEventListener` is called without stop. Is it because i am using the old api of netInfo ?

Comment: `NetInfo.isConnected. addEventListener` is deprecated. Use `NetInfo.addEventListener` to update. https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo/blob/master/src/index.ts#L162

Comment: thnx but even removing isConnected doesn't resolve the problem . Is there anything else that has changed in the way we write an addEvenListener please ?

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo#usage

Comment: thank u Sanyam Jain . Yup it's changing . Now using the new api works for me

Comment: That's great :D